# Strings equality when they contains same word in Typescript / Angular

Tags: angular, string, typescript, equality

Let's say for example I have 2 string variables like this :

```
var string1 = 'StagingFront';
var string2 = 'FrontStaging';
```

I want the if condition (string1 == string2) to return me true. If a function already exists to do that in typescript/angular it's great ! A custom function is not a problem for me, but i have no idea how to simply do that.

It should also work with this case too :

```
var string3 = 'StagingFrontProd';
var string4 = 'FrontProdStaging';
```

Comment: If the strings follow the same CamelCase pattern, as a suggestion, I would do something like this: 1) split each string as a list of CamelCase tokens (google for split camelcase regex); 2) sort both lists; 3) compare both lists  to find out if they have the same tokens, no matter which position they have on string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding the code for @antseq's explanation.

```
const str1 = this.string1.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).sort();
const str2 = this.string2.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).sort();
if(JSON.stringify(str1) === JSON.stringify(str2)) {
  console.log("matching");
} else {
  console.log("not matching")
}
```